# How to create an XSL document from XHTML?

Tags: xslt, xhtml

How to create an XSL document from XHTML? I'm trying to learn to from the [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xhtml/xhtml_syntax.htm)

I will further use this xsl created to pdf from apache fop library in c#

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: Firstly, please use this site to *ask questions*, not to *ask for help with a task*. Secondly, you need to be much more specific about what you are trying to do and where you are having difficulty.